# Restore Cforms II Form Presets

Tags: forms, mysql, plugin-cforms

I have a client who had to reactivate the [cforms II contact forms plugin](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/). It refused and gave the following error:

```
*Fatal error*: Cannot use string offset as an array in
*/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/cforms/lib_activate.php*

<http://site.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/cforms/lib_activate.php*>
on line *7*
```

After I removed the values for cforms_settings - see http://pastebin.com/THpif39S - in wp_options I was able to reactivate, but I had of course lost all form presets and automatic answers. Now I have this as value in the row cforms_settings: http://pastebin.com/JJbHhYLk .When I tried to re-add some of the serialised data I got an error from the plugin saying the settings were corrupted and that I could try to fix it or reset all.

How can I restore my form presets in the database using this serialised data as there were no recent form exports done from plugin before the plugin was deactivated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By replacing of all the serialised data I had backed up in the row with key `cforms_settings` I managed to get the form presets back. The plugin accepted this and worked as before. Life is beautiful.